# Printing out JSON objects

Tags: php, json

I am trying to figure out how to print JSON objects while looped from a database, for example, this is one JSON object

```
{
    "form name": "input distribution form",
    "ID": "5",
    "Cohort": "Cohort 1",
    "Organisation": "Concern Worlwide",
    "District": "Balaka",
    "T/A": "Kachanga"
}
```

The above is valid JSON but when its more than one object I am trying to loop through, it is displayed like this:

```
{
    "form name": "input distribution form",
    "ID": "5",
    "Cohort": "Cohort 1",
    "Organisation": "Concern Worlwide",
    "District": "Balaka",
    "T/A": "Kachanga"
}{
    "form name": "input distribution form",
    "ID": "5",
    "Cohort": "Cohort 1",
    "Organisation": "Concern Worlwide",
    "District": "Balaka",
    "T/A": "Kachanga"
}
```

Example above is now invalid JSON, these objects are being looped from a database where they were serialized PHP objects then JSON encoded to be displayed like the above.

Comment: You are probably encoding and displaying them in some form of loop, but as we can't see the code this is only a guess.  Please add the code to your question.

Comment: You are missing a comma between your two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JSON objects into a parent array

```
{
    "example": [{
        "form name": "input distribution form",
        "ID": "5",
        "Cohort": "Cohort 1",
        "Organisation": "Concern Worlwide",
        "District": "Balaka",
        "T/A": "Kachanga"
    }, {
        "form name": "input distribution form",
        "ID": "5",
        "Cohort": "Cohort 1",
        "Organisation": "Concern Worlwide",
        "District": "Balaka",
        "T/A": "Kachanga"
    }]
}
```